# Can I create a RAID0 using two partitions on the same drive?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, raid, mac, osx-snow-leopard

This question pertains to either Linux 2.6 and/or the latest Mac OS/X.

My goal is data integrity, not speed. I have way too much disk space anyway.

I gather under Linux I need to use the mdadm command. Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't think there is anything wrong with the question, just an inexperienced young'un here to learn.

Comment: Wow, two downvotes, and no comments why. Server Fault, you disappoint me again.

Answer (score 7):

First RAID0 is just striping; there's no redundancy or "integrity"
Next, If that drive fails it's taking both partitions with it. Again, no redundancy or integrity.

If you want, you *can* create a RAID1 array across two partitions. However, again if the drive fails it's taking both partitions with it, and you're back to *no redundancy*.

Comment: This is the best answer here.  If anything, make nightly backups of your documents and just keep like 2 weeks worth of backups.  A poor man's versioning system.

Comment: I'm concerned not about a complete drive failure but sectors going bad.

Comment: Modern disks (like since the turn of the century) hide bad sectors. When one starts to go bad it copies the data out and remaps the sector to a good one from it's reserve. If a drive has run out of reserve sectors you've got bigger problems, like the whole disk dieing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you meant to ask about RAID1, since that is mirroring and RAID0 offers NO data protection. You could do this, but this will probably increase the chances of data loss, since the primary thing RAID1 protects you from is drive failure, and you'll be increasing the load on the drive by doubling the writes to it, so it will be more likely to fail.